# Google Sheets - Lookup - Return last matching value problem

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, lookup, gs-vlookup

I am attaching a link to the google sheet that I am working on.

I am trying to create a list on the "sales" sheet that would pull the "next payment due" based on the last matching result from the "payments" sheet.  The cell that is used as reference is column A (ID#).  This works like an invoice number. Every time a client makes a payment towards the specific invoice #, it would be recorded on the payments sheet and the "next payment due" would be updated manually.  This new date should be reflected accordingly on the "sales" sheet.

I've tried putting the following in column K on the "sales" sheet.  It works for the first id# but not the others:

=(MAX(LOOKUP(Sales!$A6,Payments!$C$5:$C,Payments!$J$5:$J)))

LINK: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bo4WyYhD2XGAsRp_02Sft9p1ko8dyy1fgrqUrg0dM0U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: These are difference formulas that I've tried:

1) =VLOOKUP($A5, Payments!C5:J13, 8, FALSE)
     2) =(MAX(LOOKUP(Sales!$A5,Payments!$C$5:$C,Payments!$J$5:$J)))
   3) =(LOOKUP(Sales!$A5,Payments!$C$5:$C,Payments!$J$5:$J))
   4) =VLOOKUP($A5, Payments!$C$5:$J45, 8)

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many items in your columns (use countif for example if you need to) , and the last value is the 66th item for example

you can try,

```
  =VLOOKUP(B1,A3:G6,{2,3,4,....66(number of countifs you found)},FALSE)
```

for example , say countif(A:A,A1) drag down is 3,5,7,1,2,10,8

Your vlookups would be:

```
  =VLOOKUP(B1,A3:G6,{3)},FALSE)
  =VLOOKUP(B1,A3:G6,{5},FALSE)
    .....etc

  =VLOOKUP(B1,A3:G6,{8)},FALSE)
```

Put it another way, I THINK, this would answer your question for all the values you want to look up for:

```
   =VLOOKUP(B1,A3:G6,{countif(A:A;A1)},FALSE)
```

& Drag down for all your values in column B's.

research from : https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/multiple-values-using-vlookup-in-google-sheets/

Let me know if im right/it works as I just use Excel / Python, & not google sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue with the following formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LOOKUP(2,1/(Payments!$C$5:$C=$A5),Payments!$J$5:$J))
```